# Can a memory controller keep track of which OS application a memory location belongs to?

Tags: integrated-circuit, cpu, core, windows

I've included a photo of a die belonging to a modern day Intel desktop CPU.

It depicts several sections, one of which is described as the memory and IO controller.

**What I would like to know about the memory controller is whether it is able to keep track of which OS application a memory location belongs to.**

[image]

Comment: it controls the interface to the memory. Could you base your question on lecture of at least the articel on "Memory Controller" in the wikipedia and explain exactly what you did not understand? It's a bit too broad as is. Anyway: "memory", as in RAM modules, is a complex device and speaks a complex protocol over a harsh channel. You need some smarts to talk to it. That's the memory controller.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for the comment. I've updated this post with what I would really like to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The memory controller is an interface between the CPU and the DDR memory bus. The CPU’s internal idea of “memory” is somewhat different from how DDR works, because CPUs are designed at the level of memory ports that exchange cache lines, whereas DDR has a command-oriented interface that needs quite a bit of housekeeping. The controller deals with bridging this gap.

The system agent is basically an entire little PC from around the year 2000. The primary CPU is a complex supercomputer and it needs its own minder just to turn on and keep working safely. Not any different than say a Cray I that needed a minicomputer as a “system agent”.